# Can an Elastic Beanstalk from one AWS account talk to RDS in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

[image]

Security groups of Elastic Beanstalk is not recognised when adding to the Inbound Rules of RDS.

The error message is

> Could not update your security group rules (No changes were made): The
>   security group 'sg-xxxxx' does not exist

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be possible by:

1. Peering the two relevant VPC's from account 1 and account 2. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html
2. Updating the route tables of the specific VPC's subnets to ensure that traffic to and from the relevant VPC's are routed correctly.
3. Updating the security group rules in account 2 for RDS to allow source traffic from the address range VPC that account 1 will connect from, e.g. allow inbound `TCP/3306 FROM 10.0.1.0/24` as an example.

In order to provide more specific details I'd need to know the VPC CIDR range and subnet setup + configuration or route tables.

Comment: Thanks. How do I get to understand more about Step 2 i.e. updating the route tabes?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-routing.html

Comment: Thanks. Hit a blocker failing to create a peering connection as it says CIDR could have been overlapped. Not sure how to cross this hurdle.

Comment: do the two CIDR's of the VPC's overlap? e.g. are you trying to peer a 10.0.1.0/24 network with another 10.0.1.0/24?

Comment: Progress - thanks. all configuration seems went through. Had to attach an internet gateway to the VPC as well. But the RDS is not accessible from anywhere - so the talking part is not there yet

Comment: cannot connect from mysql workbench as well - (security group added for local ip)

Comment: depending on how the mysql instance we configured in RDS it may not have a public IP address. Where are you trying to connect mysql workbench from (are you inside the same VPC e.g. on an EC2 instance or bastion). If you run `dig` followed by the hostname of the RDS instance and then `ANY` what IP address are you retuned? e.g. `dig mysql.eu-west-1.rds.aws.com ANY`. You may find that the DNS only resolves from INSIDE the VPC.

Comment: could not recognise the ip address that returned. Also it said connection refused. I was trying to run mysql workbench remotely from my machine. I can access an RDS from mysql workbench that was created using default VPC but not this one